# How to add padding/dynamic edge inset to UIButton based on text size?

Tags: ios, swift, uibutton

I have a button who's title will be changing and I need the button to adjust accordingly; and maintain a certain padding. I've tried playing around with edge inset etc for a while but I have no clue why what I'm trying isn't working.
Is there anyway to get the button to dynamically decide/adjust its size so it's always got a certain padding from the text; similar to the ctrl = button in xCode?]

Thanks :)

Comment: Content edge insets do perfectly what you just described. What method did you exactly try?

Comment: I tried a few examples IE:
        titleEdgeInsets = UIEdgeInsetsMake(10, 10, 10, 10)
or the basic UIEdgeInsetsMake(10, 10, 10, 10)
I think I'm misunderstanding how to get the button's size to basically = the text's size + 10 all around

Answer (score 0):

You can set through storyboard, every button will get same padding 
[Like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hHSs2.png). Or in alternate Subclass UIButton and set that class on your desired padding button. Like this:

```
class Button: UIButton {
  override var intrinsicContentSize: CGSize {
    get {
        let baseSize = super.intrinsicContentSize
        return CGSize(width: baseSize.width + titleEdgeInsets.left + titleEdgeInsets.right,
                      height: baseSize.height + titleEdgeInsets.top + titleEdgeInsets.bottom)
    }
  }
}
```